# Functor and templates

Tags: c++, templates, functor

It is possible to distinguish when template parameter in functor represents an object or a pointer to object?

```
class Comparator
{
    public:

            template <typename Object>
            bool operator() ( const Object &o1, const Object &o2 ) const
            {
                   return ( o1.getID() < o2.getID() );
            }

            template <typename Object>
            bool operator() ( const Object *o1, const Object *o2 ) const
            {
                   return ( o1->getID() < o2->getID() );
            }
};
```

Objects or pointers are stored in generic container List, that should be sorted using the Comparator class

```
int main()
{
   List <Object *> objects1;
   std::sort(objects1.begin(), objects1.end(), Comparator()); 
   List <Object> objects2;
   std::sort(objects2.begin(), objects2.end(), Comparator());
);
```

Currently I am using two comparators (Comparator1, Comparator2) but I do not find it comfortable...

Comment: I think two objects of a same class type, will always be equal in size. You need to have another template parameter to compare objects of two different classes.

Comment: operator () can be overloaded, and member template or both. what specific problems are you having?

Comment: I solved the problem using tmeplate specialization for Object*.

Answer (score 4):

You could templatetify the `Comparator` itself:

```
template<typename Object>
class Comparator {
    public:

        bool operator()(const Object &o1, const Object &o2) const {
            return (o1.getID() < o2.getID());
        }

        bool operator()(const Object *o1, const Object *o2) const {
            return (o1->getID() < o2->getID());
        }
};
```

```
int main() {
    std::vector objects1;
    std::sort(objects1.begin(), objects1.end(), Comparator<Object> ());
    std::vector objects2;
    std::sort(objects2.begin(), objects2.end(), Comparator<Object> ());
    return 0;
}
```

This way it doesn't even generate two separate comparators!

Comment: Shouldn't the `Comparator<Object>` call for `objects1` be `Comparator<Object*>`?

Comment: I am sorry, but it does not work... The same results as using the method template. But I could specialize Comparator class, it should  work correctly.

Comment: @Tony: Nope, it's the same template specialization in both cases (and that's actually the trick here). The difference is in the selected `operator()`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your architecture (one list of `Object`s, another of `Object*`s) you really have no alternative.

Do you really need two lists?